# CiviCRM Drupal 8 installation fails - Install of pear/validate_finance_creditcard failed

Tags: drupal-8

I've been trying (for what seems like weeks now!) to install CiviCRM under Drupal 8 on a hosted cpanel server following the instructions here:

https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/drupal8/.

I keep having problems with pear/validate_finance_creditcard:

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

[RuntimeException]
Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout '/xxxx/xxxxxxxx/.composer/cache/vcs/https---github.com-pear-Validate-Finance-CreditCard.git/' '/xxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxx.xxxxx.xxx.xx/vendor/pea
r/validate_finance_creditcard' --dissociate --reference '/xxxx/xxxxxxxx/.composer/cache/vcs/https---github.com-pear-Validate-Finance-CreditCard.git/' && cd '/xxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxx.xx/vendor/pear/validate_finance_creditcard' && git remote set-url origin 'https://github.com/pear/Validate_Finance_CreditCard.git.git' && git remote add composer 'https://g
ithub.com/pear/Validate_Finance_CreditCard.git.git'

Cloning into '/xxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxx.xxxxx.xxx.xx/vendor/pear/validate_finance_creditcard'...
done.
fatal: unable to create thread: Resource temporarily unavailable
fatal: cannot repack to clean up

Has anyone else encountered this? Or anything like it? Any suggestions on what might be going wrong? Please??

It's my first time trying to get to grips with composer so it's very likely I'm missing something simple and/or obvious to the more experienced. All my attempts to modify versions, stability etc. have ended in inglorious failure – and I'm finding the multitude of options and possibilities a steep learning curve.

All help very gratefully received. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe running out of RAM? Composer does that. Try `export COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1`? An earlier version of the install docs emphasized that more but it seems to have gone missing?

Comment: Might be worth watching our install video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lrOYc_IHylw&list=PLAMgmufrZR0oNJaVqnU5Tk09nOcmKXqun&index=6. I too struggled to get it working and in fact it failed for me everytime until the video - when it worked. I had a different error and I think mine went away if I actually visited the drupal site/logged in before I completed all the steps.

Comment: Thank you both so much for taking the time to reply – even though sadly I appear to be no further forward.

I'm seriously wondering what the benefit of a tool like composer is. I've spent half my life manually resolving dependency issues. It might have taken a long time, but at least I knew where you was & what I was doing. Now I find myself dedicating a similar amount of time to learning how to troubleshoot a whole new system that's supposed to take the pain out of the process but has in fact increased it exponentially by taking control away from me. I hate stuff that doesn't work.

Comment: Just in case anyone is interested, this turned out to be an issue with the number of threads composer/git were trying to create.

The solution – at the command line change to the offending directory and configure git to limit its thread count with this command:

> git config pack.threads "1"

More information here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905257/git-push-fatal-unable-to-create-thread-resource-temporarily-unavailable

Huge thanks to those who tried to help.